# Требуется ли конечный знак...

Tags: пунктуация

...в ситуации, когда восклицательный или вопросительный знак, образующие вставку и заключенные в скобки, располагаются в конце предложения? Иными словами, предложения, схема которых имеет вид [... (!/?)], завершаются знаком, заключенным в скобки, или его наличия недостаточно для обозначения конца предложения?

Благодарю заранее.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=478#pg478

Если знак относится ко всему предложению, то ставится за скобкой. Если только к скобке, то в скобке. Конечный знак ставим, исходя из конструкции. Одно предложение - после скобки, разные предложения, в скобке - самостоятельное, одна точка перед скобкой, вторая или?, или!-в скобке, а после неё ничего.